# Kafka Mirror Maker never pulls the data from source Kafka until restart

Tags: apache-kafka, apache-kafka-mirrormaker

**Observation:**
Source Kafka is down and mirror maker is configured to pull the data from source Kafka.
It was observed that Mirror Maker tried connecting to the source Kafka for multiple times and stopped (all the retries happened in less than a minute).
Six hours later, the Source Kafka was brought up.
But, mirror maker did not start pulling the data from source Kafka.
Post mirror maker restart, it started to pull the data from source Kafka.

**Expectation:**
Mirror Maker should have automatically connected to source Kafka after 6 hours and started pulling that data without any manual intervention.

**Query:**
How can we achieve this ?
Is there a configuration in mirror maker consumer properties that can fix this ?